# Passing a C# list with 100 DTO items to front side through Ajax Post

Tags: c#, ajax, datatable, dto

I am going to show a large data C# list at the front side page.

The current condition is a C# List consist by about 100 DTO items are unable to be sent to front side from back side. it will always showing error.

Then I change a way to display, the table is put in the another page, it is being a partial view being load in the index page, it always be load again when switch page.

I am using jquery Datatable, the issue is the div and table will always shows without css style about 0.1 second then turn into with style sheet(like a flash)

I trying to find the way to solve this issue but I am unable to find so far, actually i prefer to send a complete list to front side and use for each to show it, but now I can not solve the flash page niter the ajax error

Comment: What error? You say it always shows an error. What error?

Comment: I realize the error is jsonMAxLength too short when I alert it, now I extend it so the issue had be solved! THanks